# Mysql query is working but doesn't enter the loop, PHP,MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, categories

I have one table on my database that includes kategoriID,kategoriAd,kategoriEbeveyn.
It is like categoryID,catagoryName and categoryParent.

I want that happens that is when i try to delete main category, I can delete main category and sub categories.

-World

............  +Europe

.......................  *Turkey

.................................**Istanbul

When I try to delete, This function works for World and Europe. But Turkey and Istanbul is still in my database. I couldn't delete those because of the error.

"mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"

| kategoriID | kategoriAd | kategoriEbeveyn |

|      1     |   World    |       0         |

|      2     |  Europe    |       1         |

|      3     |  Turkey    |       2         |

|      4     |  Istanbul  |       3         |

Here is my function.

```
<?php

function KategoriVeAltKategorileriSil(){
$kategoriID = $_GET['kategoriID'];
     mysql_query("DELETE FROM kategoriler WHERE kategoriID = ' $kategoriID '") or die (mysql_error());
       $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM kategoriler WHERE kategoriEbeveyn = ' $kategoriID ' ") or die (mysql_error());        

    if($delete){
         while($silinecek = mysql_fetch_array($delete)){

               KategoriVeAltKategorileriSil($silenecek[' kategoriID ']);
             echo mysql_error();
                     }
    echo "Kategori ve alt kategorileri silindi.";
    }else{ echo "Silme işlemi gerçekleştirilemedi!" .mysql_error(); }
        }

?>
```

Or Do i need to use Trigger?

Comment: Whats you table structure?

Comment: You can't fetch for DELETE request because DELETE just return the number of deleted rows. If you wan't to fetch, use SELECT statement instead

Comment: My guess is that this `while($silinecek = mysql_fetch_array($delete))`{ returns false.

Comment: You COULD set up database triggers instead of doing it in PHP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798768/trigger-delete-from-2-tables-in-mysql

Answer (score 4):

```
    function deleteCategory($kategoriID) {
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kategoriler WHERE kategoriEbeveyn='$kategoriID'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
             while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                  deleteCategory($row['kategoriID']);
             }
        }
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM kategoriler WHERE kategoriID='$kategoriID'");
    }

you can use this recursive function
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But i still have an error on this line deleteCategory($row['kategoriID']);                                                Undefined index: kategoriID in. Sorry i am newbie in php. Maybe something wrong with my switch case function.                                                                                        $Go = @$_GET['Go'];                                                         Switch($Go){                                                  case"deleteCategory": deleteCategory(); break;}

Comment: or i need to call this function like that in switch case function?          case"deleteCategory": deleteCategory($kategoriID); break;

Comment: if you are using above code then check kategoriID filed exist in your table yes you can use with case

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to make a request like :

```
DELETE FROM kategoriler WHERE ketegoriID IN (SELECT kategoriID
FROM kategoriler
WHERE kategoriID = ' $kategoriID ' or kategoriEbeveyn = ' $kategoriID ');
```

of course it's not complete because i don't know your databases structure

Answer (score 0):

Well, the point is that you have a tree structure that is mapped to the flat (row) structure of the DB.

You will need to handle this with a recursive delete method.

Your code should probably look something like:

```
function DeleteCategory(catId)
{
    GetChildCategoriesOf(catId)

    if (num_rows > 0)
    {
         foreach(ChildCategoryFound)
         {
              DeleteCategory(ChildCatId); //Recursive call
         }
    }

    Delete(catId) //Delete the parent as last action
}
```