# How do I do a delete cascade in mysql? Example provided

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables. Here are the tables and their fields.

```
articles
   id
   title
comments
   id
   content
   article_id
```

The relationship is one to many (article 1<--->* comment)

When I delete an article, I want all the article's comments to also be deleted.

What is the Trigger sql to do this?

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB? If the latter, you can set up foreign key constraints with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using InnoDB engine all you need to do is to define a FK constraint with `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Proposed schema might look like this

```
CREATE TABLE articles
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  title VARCHAR(256)
);
CREATE TABLE comments
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  content VARCHAR(10), 
  article_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (article_id) 
    REFERENCES articles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Then when you delete a row from `articles`

```
DELETE FROM articles WHERE id = 1;
```

all corresponding rows from `comments` will be deleted automatically.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2769d/1)** demo

---

Now if you're using MyISAM engine which doesn't have implementation for FKs or you for some reason want to enforce it via trigger use `AFTER DELETE` event like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ad_articles
AFTER DELETE ON articles
FOR EACH ROW
  DELETE FROM comments 
   WHERE article_id = OLD.id;
```

**Note:** It's a one statement trigger so you don't need to change `DELIMITER` and use `BEGIN...END` block.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11fe6/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested. (Change delimiter to add to db).

```
CREATE TRIGGER `article_before_delete`  
   BEFORE DELETE ON `articles` 
    FOR EACH ROW  
   BEGIN  
    DELETE FROM `comments` where `article_id` = OLD.id;
   END
```

Similar question answered here
[I want a trigger to DELETE from 2 tables in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798768/trigger-delete-from-2-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: I ran this, and included delimiter $$ <your example> delimiter ; but I got "query was empty".